# In Tritium, how can I select the previous/next element?

Tags: xpath, moovweb, tritium

I'm using the Moovweb SDK to transform a website, and I have a lot of pages with content that matches this format. There is an `<h2>` that begins a section, and that section has a random number of `<p>` elements.

Since these elements have no attributes, I can’t select by class or id. I want to select the first and last `<p>` in each section. I don’t want to have to manually select like `$('./p[1]')` , `$('./p[4]')` etc... Is there a way to select the elements before and after each `<h2>`?

```
<div>
  <h2>This is a heading</h2>
  <p>Here is some content</p>
  <p>Meh</p>
  <p>Here's another paragraph</p>
  <p>Important sentence because it's the last one</p>
  <h2>Here's a subheading</h2>
  <p>Topic sentence</p>
  <p>Bleh bleh bleh</p>
  <p>Hurray, this fragment.</p>
  <p>May the Force be with you</p>
  <p>Moovweb rocks!</p>
  <h2>New heading</h2>
  <p>More awesome content here</p>
  <p>Why is there so much stuff?</p>
  <h2>The end</h2>
  <p>Or is it?</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `preceding-sibling` and `following-sibling` selectors in XPath to do this!

The code would look something like this:

```
$("./div"){
  $("./h2") {
    $("following-sibling::p[1]") { # first p after h2
      # do stuff
    }
    $("preceding-sibling::p[1]") { # first p before h2
      # do stuff
    }
  }
}
```

See this example I created in the Tritium Tester: http://tester.tritium.io/dc25a419ac15fad70fba6fd3d3a9b512cb8430e8